# drawing Diamond of numbers with 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I need to make a diamond_look of numbers using 2D array in Java. I got my results but with null before the diamond. For `drawNumDiamond(9)` I have to get a diamond look that goes until 5 and back. I know I can make it without using array, but I want to learn more about 2D arrays :[this is how it should look like and what are my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf8PH.png)

```js
public class Example1{
   private static void drawNumDiamond(int h) {

        if(h%2 != 0) {
            int size = h/2 +1;
            int count = 1;
            int loop = 1;
            String[][] dijamant = new String[h][];
            for(int row = 0; row < dijamant.length; row++) {

                dijamant[row] = new String[row+1];

                for(int kolona=0; kolona<=row; kolona++) {

                    dijamant[0][0] = "1";

                    for(int i=0; i< loop;i++) {

                        dijamant[row][kolona]+= count;

                    }

                }
                count++;
                loop+=2;

            }

            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                System.out.printf("%" + h + "s", dijamant[k]);
                h++;
                System.out.println();
            }
            h--;
            for (int q = size - 2; q>=0; q--) {
                h--;
                System.out.printf("%" + h + "s", dijamant[q]);
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            drawNumDiamond(9);

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line :

```
dijamant[row][kolona] += count;
```

if `dijamant[row][kolona]` is `null` and `count` is 2, the result of the string concatenation will be `"null2"`. Try adding the following `if` statement before to initialize with an empty string :

```
if (dijamant[row][kolona] == null) {
    dijamant[row][kolona] = "";
}
```

This will get your code working, but there are still things to think about. E.g. you keep setting `dijamant[0][0] = "1";` in the loop.